# Jax-rs/Jersey Bean Validation on HashMap

Tags: java, validation, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I have a class that is already annotated with various constraints:

```
public class SomeBean
{
   @NotNull
   public String name;

   public String description;
}
```

I have a resource that accepts a `HashMap` of `SomeBean`:

```
public class SomeBeans extends LinkedHashMap<String, SomeBean>
{
}
```

When I try to pass in `@Valid final SomeBeans`, it does not validate each individual `SomeBean`.  For example, they can send in a `SomeBean` with a null name:

```
@POST
@Consumes( MeadiaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public SomeBeans makeSomeBeans( @Valid final SomeBeans beans )
{
  // beans is not validated!
}
```

Do I need to write a custom validator for SomeBeans or is this supported already?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no collection(or map in this case) validation support like that. Either you need to write custom validators or use [this](https://github.com/jirutka/validator-collection). Not sure if it supports maps yet though.